# Simple way to transfer data files out of a remote virtual machine

Tags: database, virtual-machine

Currently I am using Git, through the command line, to transfer data files (.csv) from my google cloud VM instance (running linux) to my local machine. However, there is limit of 25MB per file on Github. The files will be 1 GB max.

Are there other straightforward methods to do this? Maybe I can add a couple lines to the code and push the csv to a database. I have not come across a simple way to do so yet.

Comment: Linux? Windows?

Comment: This is on Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there other straightforward methods to do this?

Yes, for linux you have many options but`scp` might be most straightforward.

If you can ssh to instance directly, say `ssh user@host` or (with key) `ssh -i key user@host` then you can secure copy as well with much the similar commands:

- `scp -i key user@host:source_path/remote_file .` to copy remote file `source_path/remote_file` to current folder or viceversa
- `scp -i key local_file user@host:destination_path` to copy some `local_file` from current local folder to remote `destination_path`

Keep in mind that `user` has to have proper privileges to access remote path/file in both cases. Archiving file beforehand can help as well especially with .csv files (`tar cvzf my_archive.tar.gz my_csv_file.csv` for example).

Note: If you suffer from bad network connection that break during such a large transfer or have bunch of files that are not changed but still are part of copy procedure then `rsync` might be better option, and there are certainly much more options depending on actual requirements.